# How to access iPhone text messages without iPhone?

Tags: iphone, sms, messages-in-icloud

Is there any way to access my iPhone text messages on my PC without using my iPhone?

Otherwise, is there any way to have a second copy of my iPhone text messages
sent to my gmail?

Comment: Just to make sure.. PC is windows?

Comment: Do you mean iMessages, SMS messages, or both?

Comment: Open to using google voice?

Comment: If you've used iTunes to back up your iPhone, you can use [iExplorer](https://macroplant.com/iexplorer) to extract texts from an iPhone backup. You will need the password for the backup, however.